# How to hide Next/Previous buttons from Tumblr blog?

Tags: pagination, tumblr, infinite-scroll, tumblr-themes

In my Tumblr blog there are "Next" and "Previous" buttons. Even though I have enabled infinite scrolling in the blog, sometimes the "Next" and "Previous" buttons are visible. Like when the Internet connection is slow, these buttons shows for a while and then disappear.

What I want is that these buttons should hide permanently.

I have searched for this on Internet but all the answer are like "Delete the pagination block from the code". But after deleting the pagination, infinite scrolling also stops.

Answer (score 1):

Just add some rule into the css. It depends on the names of your elements. Something like:

```
.prev, 
.next {
   display: none; 
}
```

This would be in the style tags towards the top of the template. There should already be some existing rules for the css for these elements.

If you can update your question with the names of the navigation it might even be simpler than this.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your theme, and remove the code between

`{block:Pagination}` and `{/block:Pagination}`